# Iterate for loop after user input

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < service.journeys.Count; i++)
{
    var popup = new JourneyPopup();

    // Fill out the form
    popup.txtJourney.Text = service.journeys[i].journeyCode;
    popup.txtDays.Text = service.journeys[i].daysOfWeek;
    popup.txtDeparture.Text = service.journeys[i].departureTime;
    popup.txtOrigin.Text = service.journeys[i].description;

    popup.Show();
}
```

Inside my JourneyPopup form I have a button called 'done'. I need to iterate the for loop only after 'done' has been clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the click event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DROPtableusers Sure, but how do I pause the for loop whilst it waits for the click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try the `.ShowDialog()` function. It will not return until the dialog/form has closed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's a WinForm application and `JourneyPopup` is derived from `Form`.
Then, in the Forms designer, you can give the button a custom int value, that will be returned by the `Form.Show()` methods when the button was pressed.

At the end of your loop, you then can check this:

```
if (popup.ShowDialog() != <Returnvalue from button>)
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming WinForms or WPF? The function exists in both, but has different return values.

Comment: WinForms. Didn't even know that the `Show()` method(s) also exist in WPF.